# Customized progress bar with imageview

Tags: android, image, animation

I want to customize my own progress bar thru image view. I want to change the image view 25 times a second in a loop  in order to create a moving image. How can I do the switching of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with just the normal progressBar - Set up an animationDrawable in your drawables folder like so: (taken from the android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) on animationDrawables).

```
<!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png -- wheel5.png files inside the
  res/drawable/ folder --> 
<animation-list android:id="selected" android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Then in your code somewhere do:

```
AnimationDrawable progress = (AnimationDrawable) mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable();
progress.start();
```

Disclaimer - I haven't tested this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

link for simple tutorial about custom progress bar
[custom progress bar](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html)